# How can I effectively store data in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code and I want to know if there are any ways to store first value (className) of this array in better way? Otherwise this code duplicates

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationItem from '../navigation-item';

const className = 'mr-3';
const clN = className;

const navigationBarElements = [
  { className: clN, link: '/restaurants', name: 'ListRestaurant' },
  { className: clN, link: '/map', name: 'Map' },
  { className: clN, link: '/about', name: 'About' },
  { className: clN, link: '/contact', name: 'Contact' },
  { className: clN, link: '/login', name: 'Login' },
  { className: clN, link: '/registration', name: 'Registration' },
];

const navigationBarData = navigationBarElements.map((e) => (
  <NavigationItem
    clName={e.className}
    link={e.link}
    name={e.name}
  />
));

export default navigationBarData;
```

Comment: Can you explain what duplication you want to get rid off? If the `className` is not going to change you can simply skip adding it into your array and assign it directly to `clName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the navbar elements use the same class, why not just use a the constant `className`?

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationItem from '../navigation-item';

const className = 'mr-3';

const navigationBarElements = [
  { link: '/restaurants', name: 'ListRestaurant' },
  { link: '/map', name: 'Map' },
  { link: '/about', name: 'About' },
  { link: '/contact', name: 'Contact' },
  { link: '/login', name: 'Login' },
  { link: '/registration', name: 'Registration' },
];

const navigationBarData = navigationBarElements.map((e) => (
  <NavigationItem
    clName={className}
    link={e.link}
    name={e.name}
  />
));

export default navigationBarData;
```

If sometimes an element can have a different class in your `navigationBarElements` however, I would not worry about it. It's not a duplication of code, it's the 'duplication' of information between elements, and there's nothing wrong with that.

With gen function:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationItem from '../navigation-item';

const mr3ClassName = 'mr-3';

var createMr3NavigationBarElement = (link, name) => {className: mr3ClassName, link, name}

const navigationBarElements = [
  createMr3NavigationBarElement('/restaurants', 'ListRestaurant') // repeat for others
];

const navigationBarData = navigationBarElements.map((e) => (
  <NavigationItem
    clName={e.className}
    link={e.link}
    name={e.name}
  />
));

export default navigationBarData;
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if we need another value?

Comment: If you need a different value, there's nothing wrong with repeating the classname once per element - you have multiple elements, after all. If you really want to be pedantic, you can write a function called `createMr3NavbarElement`, which takes the link and name as params.